# How to publish message to Azure Service Bus topic from WSO2 EI/ESB?

Tags: azure, wso2, azureservicebus, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to integrate a topic in Azure Service Bus to WSO2 EI-ESB Profile. I have a message, which I have to publish to the topic "myTopic", which is in ASB.

How can I enable the sender and what are the libraries and steps to perform this operation?

I have used the libraries mentioned in the following link [Link to Article](https://medium.com/@shefandarren.173/integrating-microsoft-azure-service-bus-with-wso2-enterprise-integrator-b504895ccfe6) and used an address endpoint to publish the message, but unable to decide on how to enable the transport sender in axis2.xml, and what are the properties/parameters to be used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try uncommenting

`<transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender"/>`

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, I found out the reason for the error and resolved it.  I will update the answer.